# Simple JavaScript/HTML Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, slider, slideshow, uislider

New to Javascript, but after some research it loks like this would be the best method in implementing my desired output. I'm trying to produce a slideshow of images (5 pre-selected images) that automatically change between 5 second intervals. Can anyone point towards a tutorial or guide me along in this process? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to implement this as an exercise, or is a pre-made solution in the form of (say) a jQuery plugin acceptable? There are many freely-available slideshow scripts that can do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A really nice jQuery slideshow type plugin is this http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/
It has many different transitions between slides, and is really easy to use.

There are many out there, so a quick google search of "jQuery Slideshow" will produce hundreds of results.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a Very simple code to create simple JavaScript/HTML slideshow only by using simple JavaScript and HTML codes :

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path[0] = "image_1.gif"; 
path[1] = "image_2.gif"; 
path[2] = "image_3.gif"; 

function swapImage() 
{ 
document.slide.src = path[i]; 
if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
else i = 0; 
setTimeout("swapImage()",3000); 
} 
window.onload=swapImage; 
</script> 
<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />
```

Comment: the `language` attribute of the `script` tag is deprecated. I'd recommend using `type` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Just google for javascript content sliders

Here's 350 image and content sliders:

http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-slider-slideshow/

and here's 25 more:

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/.

Comment: Updated the URL's for current ones in 2015

Answer (score 3):

There are thousands of examples, some very complex and sophisticated. The difficoult, rather, is to find one easy to understand for beginners.

After some research I've found this from [**css-tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/). (Uses jquery also).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I though I would share my tutorial, for the benefit of anyone who comes across this question in future.

[Simple Slideshow](http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/18)

Hope this helps somebody.
Its a pretty simple and basic slideshow that is easy to build / implement.

Just In case the link becomes invalid here is the code:
The first stage is to set up the html as follows:

```
<div id="slideShow">
 <div id="slideShowWindow">
 <div class="slide">
 <img src="”img1.png”/">
 <div class="slideText">
 <h2>The Slide Title</h2> 
 <p>This is the slide text</p>
 </div> <!-- </slideText> -->
 </div> <!-- </slide> repeat as many times as needed --> 
 </div> <!-- </slideShowWindow> -->
 </div> <!-- </slideshow> -->
```

Next we will write the CSS, which is as follows:

```
img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
p{
 background:none;
 color:#ffffff;
}
#slideShow #slideShowWindow {
 width: 650px;
 height: 450px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}

#slideShow #slideShowWindow .slide {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 650px;
 height: 450px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }

#slideshow #slideshowWindow .slide, .slideText {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:18px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Myriad Pro, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
} 
.slideText {
 background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.49);
}

#slideshow #slideshowWindow .slide .slideText h2, 
#slideshow #slideshowWindow .slide .slideText p {
    margin:10px;
    padding:15px;
}

.slideNav {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -10000px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#leftNav {
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 background-image: url("../Images/plus_add_minus.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 z-index: 10;
}
#rightNav {
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 background-image: url("../Images/plus_add_green.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 z-index: 10; }
```

As you can see there isn’t anything exciting or complicated about this CSS. 
In fact it doesn’t get more basic, but I promise that’s all that’s needed.

Next we will create the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var currentPosition = 0;
 var slideWidth = 650;
 var slides = $('.slide');
 var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
 var slideShowInterval;
 var speed = 3000;

 //Assign a timer, so it will run periodically
 slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

 slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>');

 slides.css({ 'float': 'left' });

 //set #slidesHolder width equal to the total width of all the slides
 $('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

 $('#slideShowWindow')
 .prepend('<span class="slideNav" id="leftNav">Move Left</span>')
 .append('<span class="slideNav" id="rightNav">Move Right</span>');

 manageNav(currentPosition);

 //tell the buttons what to do when clicked
 $('.slideNav').bind('click', function () {

 //determine new position
 currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id') === 'rightNav')
 ? currentPosition + 1 : currentPosition - 1;

 //hide/show controls
 manageNav(currentPosition);
 clearInterval(slideShowInterval);
 slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
 moveSlide();
 });

 function manageNav(position) {
 //hide left arrow if position is first slide
 if (position === 0) {
 $('#leftNav').hide();
 }
 else {
 $('#leftNav').show();
 }
 //hide right arrow is slide position is last slide
 if (position === numberOfSlides - 1) {
 $('#rightNav').hide();
 }
 else {
 $('#rightNav').show();
 }
 }


 //changePosition: this is called when the slide is moved by the timer and NOT when the next or previous buttons are clicked
 function changePosition() {
 if (currentPosition === numberOfSlides - 1) {
 currentPosition = 0;
 manageNav(currentPosition);
 } else {
 currentPosition++;
 manageNav(currentPosition);
 }
 moveSlide();
 }


 //moveSlide: this function moves the slide 
 function moveSlide() {
 $('#slidesHolder').animate({ 'marginLeft': slideWidth * (-currentPosition) });
 }

});
```

Comment: What's with the down vote? More to the point, who thought is necessary to down vote my answer but didn't deem the situation worthy of commenting on? I have no issue with down votes but I'd like to know why, how hard is it to leave a comment? without constructive criticism how am I to improve upon my answers?

Comment: how to stop slider on hover?

Comment: To stop on hover my suggestion would be to interupt the timer function on hover. So stop the timer on mouseover and restart it on mouseleave.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it. It's working very nicely